# Parse html string Windows 8 javascript Application

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am reading in an rss feed and the description node of the feed contains html.

```
article.description = items[n].querySelector("description").textContent;
```

This is working fine. What I'd like to do is grab the first image src attribute value from the description if one exists.

This involve parsing an html block. I have tried adding jQuery (1.9) locally and it doesn't work. I've tried creating a DOMParser object but it appears this is not accessible.

Any clues how I might go about doing this? I've seen a few other similar questions without any real solution.

Summary: need to parse images out of an html string in JavaScript for Windows 8 metro app

Comment: you need regexp string.match(/<img.*/>/i);

Comment: Hi salexch.. could do i guess. was hoping there was some better way to work with html strings. But it's starting to look like there isn't.

Comment: you can add html to dom and then query it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

```
var html = '<div>Some text<img src="http://slickthought.net"/></div>';

var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = html;
var img = element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

Comment: This is the issue i am seeing everywhere. This doesn't work. It returns a length of zero regardless of what the innerHTML is.